# Scraping Multi-Row TD With Nested SPAN tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For the long story short part, just discovered BeautifulSoup yesterday, haven't done scripting or coding of any sort for many years, under time crunch, begging for help.  :)

My end goal is scraping a series of web pages with vertical style data tables and dropping to CSV.  With ye olde Google, along with my first post on stack overflow earlier today (at least first time in a decade or more), I got the basics down.  I can input a text file with the list of URLs, identify the DIV that contains the table I need, scrape the table so that the first column becomes my header, and second becomes the data row, and repeat for next URLs (without repeating header).  The snag I've hit is that the code of these pages is far worse than I thought, including a ton of extra lines, extra spaces, and now as I'm finding, nested  tags inside the  tags, most of which are empty.  But, between the spans and the extra lines, it causes the script I have so far to ignore some of the data inside the TD.  For an example of the hideous page code:

```html
                            <div id="One" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <table class="table table-borderless">

                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>ID:</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    096626 180012
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Address:</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    

                                                        
                                                            
                                                                
                                                                    
                                                                        
                                                                            
                                                                                
                                                                                            
                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                    1234  Main St
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Addr City:</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    City
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>                                      
                                            <tr>
                                                <td> Name :</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    Last name, first name<span> </span>
                                                        
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                            
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>In Care Of Address:</td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            1234<span> </span>
                                                                <span> </span>
                                                                    Main<span> </span>
                                                                        St <span> </span>
                                                                             <span> </span>
                                                                                 <span> </span>
                                                                                    
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>City/State/Zip:</td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            City<span> </span>
                                                                ST<span> </span>
                                                                    Zip<span>-</span>
                                                                        Zip+4
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>

                                        </tbody>

                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

The code I have so far is (right now, the url text file has the name of a locally stored HTML file as above, but have tested with the actual URLs to verify that part works):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import pandas as pd

contents = []
headers = []
values = []
rows = []
num = 0

with open('sampleurls.txt','r') as csvf:
    urls = csv.reader(csvf)
    for url in urls:
        contents.append(url)

for url in contents:
    html = open(url[0]).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    trs = soup.select('div#One tr')
    for t in trs:
        for header, value in zip(t.select('td')[0], t.select('td')[1]):
            if num == 0:
                headers.append(' '.join(header.split()))
            values.append(' '.join(value.split()))
    rows.append(values)
    values = []
    num += 1

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns= headers)
print(df.head())

df.to_csv('output5.csv')
```

When executed, the script seems to ignore anything that comes after a newline, or span, not sure which. The output I get is:

```
,ID:,Address:,Addr City:,Name :,In Care Of Address:,City/State/Zip:
0,096626 180012,1234 Main St,City,"Last name, first name",1234,City
```

In the "In Care Of Address:" column, instead of getting "1234 Main St", I just get "1234".  I also tried this without the join/split function, and the remaining part of the address is still ignored.  Is there a way around this?  In theory, I don't need any data inside the spans as the only one populated is the hypen in the zip+4, which I don't care about.

Side note, I'm assuming the first column in the output is part of the CSV writing function, but if there's a way to get rid of it I'd like to.  Not huge as I can ignore that when I import the CSV into my database, but the cleaner the better.

Comment: After some further digging, I discovered the decompose() function and used that to strip the span tags out of the table, but was left with the same result.  I noticed if I print the data to screen before and after the zip t.select(td[1]) part, I see the extra data there before but not after.  I'm assuming that select function or possibly the zip part is stripping the extra data, but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier with correct info in post in first place.. :)

try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
html = '''
<html>
 <body>
  <div aria-labelledby="headingOne" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordionExample" id="One">
   <div class="card-body">
    <table class="table table-borderless">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>
        ID:
       </td>
       <td>
        096626 180012
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        Address:
       </td>
       <td>
        1234  Main St
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        Addr City:
       </td>
       <td>
        City
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        Name :
       </td>
       <td>
        Last name, first name
        <span>
        </span>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        In Care Of Address:
       </td>
       <td>
        1234
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        Main
        <span>
        </span>
        St
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        City/State/Zip:
       </td>
       <td>
        City
        <span>
        </span>
        ST
        <span>
        </span>
        Zip
        <span>
         -
        </span>
        Zip+4
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
'''

contents = []
headers = []
values = []
rows = []
num = 0
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
trs = soup.select('div#One tr')
for t in trs:
    for header, value in zip(t.select('td')[0], t.select('td:nth-child(2)')):
        if num == 0:
            headers.append(' '.join(header.split()))
        values.append(value.get_text(' ', strip=True))
    rows.append(values)
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns= headers)
print(df.head())

df.to_csv('output5.csv')
```

Hope it works now with more relevant info.

The csv:

[image]

Comment: Thanks again!  Thought I had sampled enough of the page data the first go-round, then discovered how ugly the code really was. Did I mention being in a rush?  :)  For the education part, is there a quick source on what the nth-child function does?

Comment: Look here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp